# Problem when using UIColor RGB black as a key in an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, key, nsmutabledictionary, uicolor, copywithzone

I can set UIColor objects as keys in an NSMutableDictionary all day long and everything is fine and happy...

For instance:

```
[myDict setObject:foo forKey:[UIColor redColor]];
```

That works just fine... UNLESS I try to use the following:

```
UIColor *black = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
[myDict setObject:foo forKey:black];
```

That always gives me:

-[UIDeviceRGBColor copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x691be80

The reasons for why I'm defining black in the RGB colorspace are unimportant to this question, just know that I must define it that way. What I don't understand is why is this and only this color causing me a problem, and why is it that the error is a copyWithZone error?

For the record, [UIColor blackColor] works as a key, but because it isn't an RGB colorspace it is not suitable for my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the better question is "why does every other UIColor instance work as a key"?

Keys in an NSMutableDictionary "[must conform to the NSCopying protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)". `UIColor` objects don't conform to that protocol [per the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html), so you're theoretically unable to use them as keys in a dictionary.

In practice, I might guess that you're getting various concrete subclasses from a class cluster that's hidden by `UIColor`, and maybe some of them do, in fact, support NSCopying, but `UIDeviceRGBColor` does not seem to.

You could wrap the UIColor object in a thin wrapper object that *did* support NSCopying, and override `-isEqualTo:` etc to get the comparisons to work correctly, and then use those wrappers in the dictionary.

Comment: Yes this seems to make senese.  I wonder if you could implement copyWithZone in your own UIDeviceRGBColor category.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't think to check since all the predefined UIColors are working as keys... If I did a Category I'd need to override hash as well, correct?

Comment: Adding the following code in a category on UIColor seems to have fied the problem: -(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
 CGColorRef cgcopy = CGColorCreateCopy([self CGColor]);
 UIColor *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithCGColor:cgcopy];
 return copy;
}

Comment: @MGM-Diatom: Cool idea. This seems like it'll work too. Be careful, as you're leaking the CGColorRef you create here (once you've inited the UIColor with it, you can release it).